# User Search history implementation in GSA

Tags: search, google-search-appliance

I have a requirement to show users previous search history.
As far as I understand, GSA does not have this feature. Please correct me If i am wrong.

Please let me know if you have an apporach to implement this on GSA?
Please help.

Thanks,

Mohan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. You can achieve this either using the browsers local storage (ok if your users aren't mobile), otherwise you'll need to build this functionality yourself.

If you're building something yourself, take a look at the the click protocol or how the Google Analytics integration works for an example of how to track query data.